# Should we re-open the locked question "Should I use semicolons after every statement in JavaScript?"?

Tags: discussion, historical-lock

I haven't worked full-time with JavaScript for a while (mainly because my code is bug free) so I was a bit surprised to run across some example JavaScript code that didn't include semicolons at the end of each statement. It didn't look right.

I turned to Google, searching "javascript semicolon".

This question was the first result:

- [Do you recommend using semicolons after every statement in JavaScript? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/444080/do-you-recommend-using-semicolons-after-every-statement-in-javascript)

The question was locked by [Jeff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1/jeff-atwood) five years ago.

> This question exists because it has historical significance, but it is not considered a good, on-topic question for this site, so please do not use it as evidence that you can ask similar questions here. This question and its answers are frozen and cannot be changed.

I hereby explicitly dispute that this question is not both good *and* on-topic on Stack Overflow. It should be restored to its former glory and unlocked from its unfair imprisonment.

[I also couldn't see any other way to flag or otherwise the question to the attention of a mod.]

Just to spell out the arguments for this question being on-topic:

1. I just encountered, as a programmer engaged in programming, the nominal subject of this site, example code for a pretty nice project, that inspired the exact question.
2. The question is *the* top search result for a reasonable first Google search aimed at answering the actual real-life question I wanted to know.

Also, per the current help:

- The question is "a specific programming problem"
- It is "a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development"
- It is *not* "seeking debugging help"
- It *is* a problem that can 'still be reproduced' (tho funnily it kind of *is* a "typographical error")
- It is *not* asking for "homework help"
- It is not asking for a recommendation for an "off-site resource" (because how dare we care about anything other than our dear sweet SO)

Neither is this a subjective question. As the existing answers demonstrate there are specific concrete cases where semicolons or the lack thereof significantly change the behavior of the code.

Maybe Jeff thought the question was soliciting opinions. That's not the case; there's a real answer.

Comment: What are your arguments for it being on-topic?

Comment: It's a polling question: *My question is, do you leave them out?*. How is a question that explicitly asks for opinions on topic?

Comment: I'm confused.  Why'd this question deserve closure?

Comment: @Makoto it doesn't ...

Comment: I know it is off-topic, but why am I nervous about not being able to vote? D;

Answer (score 8):

Problem is, you're bound to get opinions on this.  [There *are* hard facts](https://www.codecademy.com/en/forum_questions/507f6dd09266b70200000d7e) about this, but whether or not you *should* is going to be a matter of opinion.  Many will advocate for the sake of readability.  Others will advocate for the sake of simplicity.  Both are opinionated stances.

Locking this question IMO was a bit...much.  A better question in the modern day would be, "When would I need semicolons in JavaScript, and when wouldn't I?"  I don't see reason to unlock this question and edit it, just to invalidate its existing answers.  I see reason to remove it, but that's just me...

Comment: The is one of those cases where the core question is a good on-topic one, but the way it's phrased makes it off-topic. *Editing* is the solution in such cases, not closing or locking. Often they're very simple edits.

Comment: All of the info at your link would make for an even better answer than the existing ones. The best answers are those that explicitly detail exactly when and when not to do something like what's being asked.